# Router reboots when doing port-scanning

Tags: router, port-forwarding, port-scanning

I'm facing a problem similar to [Router reboots when using Nmap](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103505/router-reboots-when-using-nmap). To sum up, I'm doing port-scanning and once the rate is high enough the router reboots (just like described in the thread above using nmap). What I'm looking for is a solution to prevent the router from rebooting, while still keeping the scanning rate.

I've already tried to post this problem on security stackexchange, it was put on hold as off-topic [Router reboots when doing port scan [on hold]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220248/router-reboots-when-doing-port-scan)
. I hope this is the correct forum to ask this then.

Anyway I was advised there to include the router logs. My router - FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360 (FRITZ!OS 06.30) - looses all the logs when doing a reboot. I've also tried my routers Push-Service to get the error logs before the reboot, but without success. So the only thing there is, is an error message after the reboot, but without any further information about the error itself :/.

The accepted answer for [Router reboots when using Nmap](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103505/router-reboots-when-using-nmap) says

> You are probably exhausting the router's resources, primarily the NAT table.

I'm not an expert to this, but I was thinking that if I do port forwarding just like with an http server for port 80, but instead to it for port equal to the source port of the TCP probes I'm sending, it would solve this issue described in the answer there. But it does not help me, the router still reboots. Am I wrong in thinking that port forwarding can help with this issue, or does it mean that I have a different problem and how can I solve this?

BTW I'm using all kind of TCP SYN like scans and there is not a notable difference in terms or router rebooting behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy a professional router that does not reboot then (it shouldn't, but it is a home model not prepared to be pushed towards such resource limits). Or log a bug ticket at Fritz (as reboot is not a proper behaviour, indepenent of whether ressources are exhausted at some point).

I don't understand Your question regarding port forwarding exactly.
Probably You mean You do not configure any port forwarding effecting this scenario and where possible the router uses the same source port for outgoing connection from public IP to the internet. That is true and quite default behaviour, but is anyway NAT if we are talking about a default FritzBox setup on a default IPv4 or Dual-Stack consumer DSL connection. The router has to translate the connection from Your internal network to the public IP, thought most of the time it can pick same source port as the incoming connection used, for convenience. But it still has to remeber the initiating connection/source-ip and port to send the answer packets back. Whether some PAT has to be done in addition to NAT should not make a big difference.

If You use IPv6 on a default connection where You get a range of public IPv6 addresses which Your client get assigned and used, then You do not use NAT. (Anyway even then there might be ressources that are exhausted at some point which could make such a non-well-behaving device reboot.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With port forwarding I was meaning that I have set my router to forward one publicly accessible port of my public IP address to one unique local machine with a specified port. This exact port is being used as source port of the probe packets. Therefore I do not understand why it still has to keep track of the connection source ip and port when all answer packets all have only one possible destination which i specified by port forwarding, no?

Comment: No, in that case (if it is really like You think) the router does always NAT+PAT (so possible even more expensive then only NAT but at least not cheaper).  Your originating source port has to be translated to a different port every time as it needs the port to listen for incoming connections for the NAT rule so cannot use it at the same time to wait for response packages for outgoing connections.  Also I thougth that the fast modes use some kind of parallelization so I wonder how that can play together with a specific source port. You should post You exact nmap command line to get some hints.

Comment: Also just for clarity You should write from where You scan what (from internal network machine through Internet-Access-Router to public IP(s) somewhere in the internet via IPv4 is what the accepted answer You refer to assumes).

Comment: Ok well, that is really counter-intuitive, at least from the perspective the problem is originating from. So I'm having a C code sending and receiving packets by "hand" with raw sockets. And ports just don't play a role there yet. I receive all kinds of packets independent whether incoming or outgoing connection. I guess it will take me some time to understand why there is still a translation needed even if the port is forwarded... And yes any nmap command with a sufficient high scanning rate has the same router reboot effect. My C code and nmap are basically just doing the same thing.

Comment: Exactly I scan from internal network machine through Internet-Access-Router public ipv4s. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The router and the OS (and a normal application) needs to know which TCP connection a packet belongs, so it has to use the TCP ports to distinguish between them and the router has to do the same. For UDP it's almost the same butthere is no connection from network point of view and it is commonly used on routers/firewalls to allow answer packages with reversed adressees - and to do NAT/PAT beause You could have different targets.

Comment: You could establish a PPPoE from Your machine if You can enable PPPoE passtrough on FritzBox and Your provider allows mutiple conections. Or You might be able to configure Your fritzbox as some kind of RAW router for the DSL connection to be able to establish PPPoE connection from Your device but would loose much of the functionality of fritzbox then (iE the FritzBox has no Internet-Connection, so no other device can go into internet without passing Your local PPPoE router first and can not establish telephony services which depends on IP Internet and not just DSL-Ethernet connection).

Comment: For port-scanning the TCP connection is never really established (half-open), but I guess that does not play a role for the router. I have full access to both IP and TCP headers, is there maybe anything I can try from within this header field values, like e.g. including some option that may help? I'll definitely have a look at PPPoE, thank you for that.

Comment: I mean theoretically I could even alter the ethernet header. Is there something in this direction that i can do in order to prevent this NAT/PAT table chaos?

Comment: No, there is no chaos. At sound like You would like to introduce some. And no, the fritzbox is a "blackbox" with limited configurability. So You need another router or a PPPoE connection through the Firtzbox from a device where You have more or less full control over such things.

Comment: A new TCP connection is always a new session. A new socket has to be created or some socket needs to be reset. The outgoing packet reaching Your FritzBox is just a new session. The fritz box assigns a free source port for the outgoing connection for this new session and remebers the source port and ip so it can send the response there. But if You are talking about RAW sockets and Port numbers do not matter, maybe You are just doing something that is not valid TCP or UDP (or another IP protocol the FritzBox can forward) and causing a crash of the box because oif that?

Comment: I'm doing TCP SYN like scans https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner#SYN_scanning. I send a packet (e.g. SYN) and wait for the response (e.g. SYN/ACK) and then send RST. I dont think there is a problem with the code, because it behaves similar to nmap considering the fritz. And it works fine for sufficient low scanning rate ~300 ports/min. I'm seeking for 1000 ports/min which is still fairly low in my opinion. I should mention that I'm resending the SYN packets a few times in order to overcome possible filtering (at least to try to overcome filtering). So the real rates may be a bit higher.

Comment: Yes ok, but still the RFC recommend NAT devices to not delete the entry immediately to allow possibly later arriving response packets to be delivered to the recipient (to not cause any loss of information). The RST is intended for the recipient and the TCP spec does not state that there must no further response arriving at the sender of RST. So NAT device should be polite and forward packages, the might have been sent before the RST have been sent and the RST sender expects to receive these packages. So it's normal that NAT device is not dropping the mapping immediately.

Comment: IP and TCP themselves do not include the topic NAT so there is nothing defined in the protocol to talk to the NAT device (the NAT device is meant to be transparent and is not a proxy with an own protocol).